# Installation error message regarding EMC Atmos Evaluation

Tags: emc

When I am trying to install the EMC Atmos Evaluation Edition on an ESX host, I get the following error message

```
No MDS is Master [Fatal]
```

when I run the command

```
./mds-shutdown.pl --shutdown --RMG
```

on the first VM AEE-r1s1-001.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?